# Как работает DIV?

Tags: ассемблер

Вот есть следующий код:

```
MOV AX, -127
CBW
MOV BL, 4
DIV BL
```

Как я понимаю AL/BL. Или же AX/BL? При чём остаток идет в AH, а частное в AL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае есть смысл от команды CBW?
Мы же не преобразуем Байт в Слово (Слово уже есть в AX).

Будет AX/BL, остаток идет в AH, а частное в AL.

[DOC](http://www.kolasc.net.ru/cdo/programmes/assembler/div.html)

Comment: А почему слово уже есть в AX?

Comment: @Jeremen1 а зачем там первая команда?

Comment: @Jeremen1, немного уточню что хотел сказать @alexlz.
AX - это регистр состоящий из 2 байт (Слово) AL + AH. Команда CBW приводит Байт к Слову, то есть AL -> AX. Но так как мы уже оперируем с регистром AX, то нет смысла делать CBW. А старшие биты и так будут заполнены единицами, так как число отрицательное и в без знаковом варианте будет 65409 (0x0FF81).